# get the error value from linear regression function lm

Tags: r

i have a linear regression problem which i solved using:

```
m=lm(value ~ mean, data=d)
```

and from this value i can get the R2 and the regression equation.

but i want to get the standard error(fitting error). i was able to see the value but i don't know how to get it in order to store it inside a data frame.

i get the value using `summary(m)` and the result is something like this:

```
Call:
lm(formula = value ~ mean, data = d)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-25.000 -15.909  -2.124  14.596  44.697 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.500e+01  1.064e+00   23.49   <2e-16 ***
mean        -1.759e-06  1.536e+00    0.00        1    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 16.85 on 1298 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 1.01e-15,   Adjusted R-squared: -0.0007704 
F-statistic: 1.311e-12 on 1 and 1298 DF,  p-value: 1
```

so the question is: how can i get access to these values??

thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function `summary` just returns an R list.

```
##Generate some dummy data
x = runif(10);y = runif(10)
m = summary(lm(y ~ x))
```

We can use the usual list syntax to extract what we want. For example,

```
m[[4]]
```

Returns a data frame of model fits

```
R> m[[4]]
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.44265     0.2443  1.8123   0.1075
x            0.07066     0.4460  0.1584   0.8781
```

and `m[[6]]` returns the `Residual standard error`

```
R> m[[6]]
[1] 0.2928
```

There are a few convenience functions around, such as `coefficients(m)`

Comment: I think so, but you're probably in a better place to assess that.

Comment: so, lets think that i made the error function which is the sum(from 0 to a) of the first part + the sum(from a to length) for the second part. and in the sum we have some function of the intercept and slope. this value should be the result of this function??right??

Comment: so it's basically the sum of squared residuals of the model that i want. is this the value that you gave me? or it's another one??

Comment: You can get the RSS by: `sum((fitted(lm(y~x)) - y)^2)' or `m[[6]]^2*(n-1-p)` where `n` is the sample size and `p` is the number of predictors.

Comment: thank you very much, i think i will get the same result by summing the squred resides..

Answer (score 3):

Access residuals using `resid(m)`.

EDIT: From the comments, it seems that you want `sum(resid(m) ^ 2)`.

Comment: i tried reside(m) and i got like a lot of rows, what does this means?? i want the fitting error.

Comment: i want the fitting error.
so basically what i want is the value of the error. e.g the linear regression works on minimizing the error function. so i need the value of this error function.

Answer (score 0):

Extract Residual Standard Deviation 'Sigma'

```
sigma(m)
```